# Best way to read and process parquet files stored in GCP using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I am new to using GCS. I am using it to store some parquet data files. Previously before GCS, I was storing all of my parquet files locally on my machine to test some code to read all of the parquet files into a data frame using Spark.

Here is an example of what I had setup to work locally in python:

```
source_path = '/mylocal/directory/files'


appName = "PySpark Parquet Example"
master = "local"
# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read parquet files
df = spark.read.parquet(
    source_path)
```

Now that I have moved to storing all of the source data into a bucket in GCS, I am a little lost as to where to start with an equivalent method to accessing the files that are now stored in a folder within my GCS bucket. I have looked into gsutil and other libraries but am open to any suggestions as to the easiest way to go about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you are trying to access the parquet files stored in gcs bucket from your local spark. If that's the case, please follow the below sequence of steps

1. Download the gcs-hadoop-connector.jar and place it inside your jars folder in your local spark. Note: Please download the correct matching version from the below link (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/gcs-connector).
2. Create and download the service account json file with storage access to read/write the data into the gcs bucket.
3. Update your hadoop configuration in spark code as below

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]") \
                   .appName('readParquetData') \
                   .getOrCreate()
conf =spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl","com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", projectId)
conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", secretLocation)
conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
```

4. Now you can read the data in gcs using spark using the below code

```
df=spark.read.option("header",True).parquet(location)
```

Complete Code :

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]") \
                    .appName('readParquetData') \
                    .getOrCreate()
conf =spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl","com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", projectId)
conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", secretLocation)
conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")

df=spark.read.option("header",True).parquet("gs://bucketName/folderName")
df.show()
```

Please approve the answer, if it helps to resolve your issue. Thanks